# Find Noncurrent version objects in a very large S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a very large S3 bucket (over 100 million objects).

From looking at `AWS Storage Lens` I see that I have lots of `Noncurrent version objects` in that bucket (lots of objects and lots of bytes in total). Over 20%.

From the planned usage for this bucket, this looks strange to me, as I expect to have less than 2%.

How can I find these objects on large scale so I can decide how to act upon that prboelm?

Can I have somehow an analysis of "Noncurrent Version bytes" per prefix or any other form that will help me track down where these objects are concentrated and fix my usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think requesting the [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) could be helpful. When you do this, you can decide whether:

> whether to list all object versions or only current versions,

Once you have this, further analysis can be simplified using AWS Athena which can query the inventory CSV file.